# Proving that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{k^3-|\sin k|}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I'm currently practicing proving series convergence and divergence and ran across this problem. The answer says it's convergence, and I have been trying to prove why.

So far, I set $a_{n}=\frac{k}{k^{3}-k}$. So, $\sum\frac{k}{k^{3}-k}$.

Then, using the limit comparison test $$\lim\dfrac{\dfrac{k}{k^3-\left|\sin k\right|}}{\dfrac{k}{k^{3}-k}}=_{t=\frac{k}{k^{3}-k}}\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\dfrac{1}{\sin t}}{t}=\infty$$

Therefore, my "proof" says that this series diverges instead of converges.

I'm not exactly sure what I did wrong. Was I on the right track? Or is there another method that I should or could use?

Comment: The limit is fine to use, but might I suggest using a comparison with $\sum\frac {k}{k^3-k}$ or similar?

Comment: Your substitution is incorrect. If you put $t=k/(k^3-k)$ in $k/(k^3-|\sin k|)$ you get $$
\frac{{\sqrt {1 + 1/t} }}{{(1 + 1/t)^{3/2}  - \left| {\sin (1 + 1/t)} \right|}}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that:

(1) $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{k^3-|\sin(k)|}$ is a series with non-negative terms (why?) and

(2) $\frac{k}{k^3-|\sin(k)|}\leq\frac{1}{k^2}$ (why?).

Knowing this, there is a criterion you can use to conclude that the series converges (which one?).